# Mess of right-to-left and left-to-right in Unicode

Tags: unicode, editing, text-editing

How good Kate editor  supports right-to-left text? I see a mess of the order. Not sure whether it is a "feature" of Unicode standard or a Kate bug.

http://imagebin.ca/v/1EUMnLMK27aX

I don't see where these FUTURE/PAST comments start and where they end.

More generally (not only about Kate): Is there a way to edit Unicode files without a mess of directions?

... for example I want XML comments to look `<!-- ... -->` not `<-- ... --!>`. Is it possible at all, when editing mixed direction files?

Comment: What is Kate editor and what specific problem are you referring to? “Mess” is not a problem description. You should describe the issue in a self-contained manner, so that one does not need to look at an external linked resource and guess what you see as a problem.

Comment: i'm not sure off hand but maybe if the left to rightness is done by an inherent reading of the unicode characters (e.g. are these unicode characters hebrew, if so, make them right to left), or whether they're done from a font. If the latter then it'd affect all 'cos a text file can't have multiple or any really, fonts, just the one(or ones in theory, but in practice, one), set in the text editor. For direction to be done inherently based on unicode character is possible in theory but may be a bit hopeful. But I don't know off hand.

Comment: your pic isn't showing up for me, can you give a link to imgur with it? you can go to imgur.com and literally paste it and you get a link.

Comment: @barlop: http://i.imgur.com/cniqyUf.png

Comment: One specific problem is that XML comments are displayed right to left (which obviously should be left to right). See the linked image

Comment: I see that kind of thing in the google search bar too.. but if I type the XML backwards while it is flushed from right to left(ctrl-right shift), then it works http://i.imgur.com/21MXzLo.png  Though if I type it while it's flushed left to right(ctrl-left shift) then I flush it right to left(ctrl-right shift), then it doesn't work. Maybe if you're eright to left, the xml tags should look funny, like  <!-- should look like   --!>     By the way it is possible to get the letter direction right to left, with the words still flushed left to right.

Comment: a long shot but maybe this page here helps http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0101.htm    go to view..source they seem to have the HTML the correct way around and the hebrew the correct way too. you could save that file and see how it opens in kate. or could try copy/pasting it.